# Mouse Click event runs multiple times and freezes browser

Tags: javascript, event-handling, mouseevent, addeventlistener

I am creating a class that creates a scatter plot graph that allows the user to click on a point to see the entities which have those values. I am wanting to use vanilla JS to do this.

I am using an event listener to detect when the user clicks on the HTML canvas - this works...for a little while.

It seems that the code within the event listener will run at least 3 times (when it should only run once). After clicking on my canvas a few times, the entire browser locks up. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the JavaScript, the if statement at the start is my attempt to stop the code from running multiple times (which does not work):

```
var cv = document.getElementById(mainCanvas.id);
    cv.addEventListener('click', function (e)
    {
        if (scatterPlot.mouseProgress == 1)
        {
            //Mouse is over the canvas
            var mouseX = e.pageX;
            var mouseY = e.pageY;

            //Cycle throug the points to see if the current x/y match
            var show = false;
            var listDesc = [];
            var count = 0;
            var length = range.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                if (mouseX < range[i].clickRight && mouseX > range[i].clickLeft && mouseY < range[i].clickBottom && mouseY > range[i].clickTop)
                {
                    show = true;
                    listDesc[count] = [];
                    listDesc[count]["desc"] = range[i].description;
                    listDesc[count]["valOne"] = range[i].x;
                    listDesc[count]["valTwo"] = range[i].y;
                    count++;
                }
            }

            //Show the descriptions if needed
            if (show)
            {
                scatterPlot.drawDescriptionBox(mouseX + 10, mouseY + 10, listDesc, mainCanvas);
            }
            else
            {
                //Clear the screen and redraw the graph
                scatterPlot.clearGraph(mainCanvas);
                scatterPlot.plot(range, mainCanvas.id);
            }
        }
        //Stop the mouse down event from progressing
        if (scatterPlot.mouseProgress == 1)
        {
            scatterPlot.mouseProgress = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            scatterPlot.mouseProgress = 1;
        }
    });

    cv.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e)
    {
        scatterPlot.mouseProgress = 0;
    });
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mumwhrm0/

Comment: Is it possible to create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Yes I can. I have edited my question to include this.